# How to dial modem without sudo

Tags: networking, sudo, internet-connection, modem, modem-manager

I am using **ixconn** as modem manager because it has many more features than the default network manager. But it cannot be used without root privileges (i.e., `sudo`). How can I use **ixconn** to dial my modem, without `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to edit your sudoers file (with visudo) to accomplish this. This will still make you use sudo, but will not require a password.

```
sudo visudo
```

This will bring up the sudoers file in nano. Add a line like this:

```
Cmnd_Alias MODEM_CMDS = /path/to/ixconn, /path/to/othermodemsoftware
```

and then one like this:

```
regularuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: MODEM_CMDS
```

Obviously, replace the paths to any programs you want to run with actual paths, and replace regularuser with the user you want to be able to use ixconn without a password. You can also specify groups instead of users, by placing a % in front of the group name, like this:

```
%modemgroup
```